# Show that the function is continuous

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f:A \rightarrow R$. Suppose that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a continuous function $g:A \rightarrow R$ so that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$, for each $x$ in $A$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

Could you help me to show this? How do I start? By using the fact that $g$ is continuous?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can choose a $g_n$ for which

$$|f(x) - g(x)| < \frac 1 n$$

Now what do you know about the uniform limit of continuous functions?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a\in A$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Consider a continuous $g$ for $\varepsilon/3$, and let $\delta$ be given by continuity of $g$ at $a$ for $\varepsilon/3$. Then, with $x\in A$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$, we have
$$|f(x)-f(a)|\le|f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-g(a)|+|g(a)-f(a)| <\varepsilon\,.$$